# JSON Data not printing to the Xcode console and won´t display on one of my tab views

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, urlsession

I am trying to decode a JSON file from a URL, but I am having issues initially.

Error: Error decoding JSON: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "jobs", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "jobs", intValue: nil) ("jobs").", underlyingError: nil))

My code is below.

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct ContentViewJobs: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProductListView()
    }
}

struct Job: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title, description: String
    let isRemote, isActive: Bool
    let locations: [Int]
}

class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    struct Returned: Decodable {
        let jobs: [Job]
    }

    @Published var jobsArray: [Job] = []
    @Published var filteredJobs: [Job] = []
    
    let apiKey = "MyAPIKey"

    
    func fetchData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.forager.ai/v1/job_search/") else {
                print("Invalid URL")
                completion()
                return
            }

            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.addValue("Bearer \(apiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Network error: \(error)")
                    completion()
                    return
                }

                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Returned.self, from: data)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.jobsArray = decodedData.jobs
                            self.filteredJobs = self.jobsArray
                        }
                        completion()
                    } catch {
                        print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
                        completion()
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }

struct ProductListView: View {
    @StateObject private var dataManager = DataManager()
    @State private var searchText: String = ""

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if dataManager.jobsArray.isEmpty {
                Text("Loading Data...")
            } else {
                VStack {
                    SearchBar(text: $searchText, placeholder: "Search Jobs")
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                        .padding(.top, 14)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 22)
                        .background(Color.white)

                    
                    List(0..<dataManager.filteredJobs.count) { index in
                        let job = dataManager.filteredJobs[index]
                        NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetailView(Job: job)) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
//                                WebImage(url: URL(string: product.thumbnail))
//                                    .resizable()
//                                    .scaledToFit()
//                                    .frame(height: 150)
//                                    .cornerRadius(8)

                                Text(job.title)  // Use 'job.title' instead of 'Job.title'
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .foregroundColor(.pink)
                                    .padding(4)

                                
                                Text(job.description)
                                    .font(.callout)
                                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                    .padding(4)
                                
//                                Text(product.category)
//                                    .font(.headline)
//                                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
//                                    .padding(4)

                                
                                Text(job.isRemote ? "Remote" : "Not Remote")
                                    .font(.headline)
//                                    .bold()
                                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                    .padding(4)



//                                Text("brand: $\(String(format: "%.2f", product.brand))")
//                                    .font(.subheadline)
//                                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            }
                            .padding(12) // Add padding around the entire VStack
//                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)

                        }

                    }
                    .listStyle(PlainListStyle()) // or .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())


                }

            }

        }

        .onAppear {
            dataManager.fetchData {
                print("Products Array: \(dataManager.jobsArray)")
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: searchText) { newValue in
            if !searchText.isEmpty {
                dataManager.filteredJobs = dataManager.jobsArray.filter {
                    $0.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
                }
            } else {
                dataManager.filteredJobs = dataManager.jobsArray
            }
        }
    }

}

struct ProductDetailView: View {
    let Job: Job
    

    //This view is presented after a Job cell is slected
    var body: some View {
        Text("Job Detail View")
        Text(Job.title)
    }
}

struct Returned: Decodable {
    let jobs: [Job]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case jobs
    }
}


struct SearchBar: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                .padding(.vertical, 12)
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding(.trailing, 0)
                .foregroundColor(.black)  // Set the text color

                .onTapGesture {
                    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.becomeFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The forager JSON format looks like this:

{
"page": 0,
"job_source": "linkedin",
"date_featured_start": "2019-08-24",
"date_featured_end": "2019-08-24",
"organization_ids": [
0
],
"title": "string",
"description": "string",
"is_remote": true,
"is_active": true,
"locations": [
0
]
}

I have tried debugging the code with print statements at all places in the code and debugging. My iOS simulator displays the tab titled "No products available."

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: To simplify you current code, you have:  `if empty { } else { View.onAppear { fetch() }}`, write just that. When is called `fetch()` in your opinion? That's your issue. You are calling fetch when the view that's should appear when you've already fetched appears... It's like double negation... You might want to fetch onAppear of the NavigationView, or on EmptyView onAppear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, where you have the `.onAppear{...}` attached to the `NavigationStack`
(note NavigationView is deprecated). Also decode the json data using a valid `Returned` model and
using `@StateObject` for your `dataManager`.

Works well for me, using MacOS 14.2, with Xcode 15.1, tested on real ios17 devices and MacCatalyst.

You will need to consult the docs of the API to determine if any of the properties
of `Returned` and `Product` are optional, and add `?` to those.

Full working code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProductListView()
    }
}

class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var productsArray: [Product] = []  // <--- here

    func fetchData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://compassjobsapp.net/DummyJSONData.json") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            completion()
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Network error: \(error)")
                completion()
                return
            }

            if let data = data {
                    print("Received Data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Unable   to convert data to string")")
                do {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Returned.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.productsArray = decodedData.products  // <--- here `s`
                        print("Decoded Data: \(decodedData)")
                        print("Products Array: \(self.productsArray)")
                    }
                    print("Decoded Data: \(decodedData)")
                    completion()
                } catch {
                    print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
                    completion()
                        
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ProductListView: View {
    @StateObject private var dataManager = DataManager()  // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {  // <--- here
            if dataManager.productsArray.isEmpty {
                Text("No products available")
            } else {
                List(dataManager.productsArray) { products in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetailView(product: products)) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                            // commented for my testing
//                            WebImage(url: URL(string: products.thumbnail))
//                                .resizable()
//                                .scaledToFit()
//                                .frame(height: 150)
//                                .cornerRadius(8)

                            Text(products.title)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)

                            Text("Price: $\(String(format: "%.2f", products.price))")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        }
                        .padding(10)
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Products")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {  // <--- here
            dataManager.fetchData {
                print("Products Array: \(dataManager.productsArray)")
                // Print the products array to the console
                print(dataManager.productsArray)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProductDetailView: View {
    let product: Product  // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        Text("Product Detail View")
        Text(product.title)
    }
}

struct Returned: Codable {
    let products: [Product]   // <--- here, note `s`
    let total, skip, limit: Int
}

struct Product: Identifiable, Codable {  // <--- here
    let id: Int
    let title, description: String
    let price: Int
    let discountPercentage, rating: Double
    let stock: Int
    let brand, category: String
    let thumbnail: String
    let images: [String]
}
```